# Randomly Select a Value from One Row when Merging Rows

Tags: r

I want to merge the rows in the following dataframe so that there is only one of each var1:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c('a', 'a','b','c'), var2=c(1,2,3, 4), var3=c(2, NA, NA, 4), var4=c(4, 3, 2, 1))

  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    a    1    2    4
2    a    2   NA    3
3    b    3   NA    2
4    c    4    4    1
```

Most advice seems to be to use something like this:

```
df2 <- ddply(df1,"var1",fun = sum())
```

Or possibly group_by would be another solution.

Unfortunately I have to follow two rules:

1) if the duplicate row has an NA and a number then keep the number;

2) if the duplicate row has two numbers then randomly select one number to keep.

So the resulting data should look something like this:

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    a    2    2    4
2    b    3   NA    2
3    c    4    4    1
```

where row 1 var2 could be 1 or 2 and row 1 var 4 could be 3 or 4.

EDIT:

Prem's solution works sometimes, but not always. I don't understand the mechanics of the code to explain why it doesn't always work but if you run the following example a few times you eventually get an NA result when there needs to be a value:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c('a', 'a','a','c', 'c'), var2=c(1,2,3,4,NA), var3=c(2, NA, NA, NA,5), var4=c(4, 3, 2, NA,1))


library(dplyr)

#set.seed(1)   #comment this to have random sample

df1 %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  fill(var2:var4, .direction = "down") %>%
  sample_n(1)


  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    a    1    2    4
2    a    2   NA    3
3    a    3   NA    2
4    c    4   NA   NA
5    c   NA    5    1
```

I often get the following which is correct:

```
    var1  var2  var3  var4
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      a     3     2     2
2      c     4     5     1
```

But I also sometimes get the following which is incorrect:

```
    var1  var2  var3  var4
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      a     3     2     2
2      c     4    NA    NA
```

Comment: you want to sum others variable values ? or just take radomly one ?

Comment: When there are two value then randomly take one. When there is only one value then take that one. Rows that are not duplicated don't change.

Comment: df2 <- subset(df1,!duplicated(var1)) does not work because it chooses the first value, not the number or randomly choosing between both numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)   #comment this to have random sample

df1 %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  fill(var2:var4, .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(var2:var4, .direction = "up") %>%
  sample_n(1)
```

Output:

```
  var1   var2  var3  var4
1 a      1.00  2.00  4.00
2 b      3.00 NA     2.00
3 c      4.00  4.00  1.00
```

Sample data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), var3 = c(2, 
NA, NA, 4), var4 = c(4, 3, 2, 1)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", 
"var3", "var4"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work consistently. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
df2 <- subset(df1,!duplicated(var1))
```

**Output**

```
df2
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    a    1    2    4
3    b    3   NA    2
4    c    4    4    1
```